# Swift UITableView scrollToRow or setContentOffset doesn't scroll to appropriate position

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have tried both

```
let rect = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.origin.y+self.additionalContentOffset), animated: true)
```

and

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: scrollPosition, animated: true)
```

And in some cases it works ok in others it is a little jumpy and ends on a wrong position/row in table view.
What is the reason that scrollView/tableView is not scrolled to correctly?